# R, command line, write.csv2 to file fails into of a schedule a task

Tags: r, batch-file, db2

I am trying to automate (on a Win7 system) an R script to read data from a DB2 data base and write it to file, for processing by another system. My code runs in the R gui perfectly. So I wrote a batch file to call this .r file and output results to script.out as shown below. When I double click the batch file everything runs successfully. When I schedule a task to run the batch file, the R code runs, collects data from DB2 data base, but the write to file fails every time, only save the header from sql query.

R Code:

```
library(RJDBC)

library(rJava)

jcc = JDBC("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver",".../db2jcc4.jar")

conn = dbConnect(jcc,"xxx",user="xxxx",password="xxxx")

bd1 = dbSendUpdate(conn, "set current schema PRODUCCION")

bd1 = dbSendQuery(conn,paste("SELECT *FROM VW_tabla_1"))

dat4<- fetch(bd1, n = -1)

write.csv2(dat4,file = ".../bd1.csv",row.names = F)

dbDisconnect(conn)
```

batch file code:

```
\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave "C:\Users\abg\SkyDrive\Documents\dat.R"
```

thanks for help me.

Comment: You might need to put your code in the code block for readability

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer, but an overly long comment of things to look at.

It looks like you're well on your way to debugging it by trying it in different conditions. I'm going to suggest some next steps to try and figure out the part that fails. It seems that writing to the file isn't a problem, so I'm gonna skip all the parts about different writing rights.

- try writing some text to the file, not query results - tests that write.csv line works in scheduled way.
- try a dummy query, like `select "a"` or however the dummy queries work in DB2 - tests that you're actually connected to database
- try selecting the number of rows from that table and writing that to file - tests that the table actually has rows in it

If I understand things correctly, then one of these steps should fail and give you an idea where to look next. Good luck!

PS. How do you schedule tasks to run under Win 7?

Answer (score 0):

I get finally to solve this problem. In my sql query had special characters such as accents, in the R gui these are interpretable but not in the scheduled task, so the solution was to change these special characters in the sql query and all ran ok.